# How to display active directory browser from powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory

I have a GUI for AD user creation. One of the parameters I put in is location where the user shall be created. For now I have it in a text box as a simple text (ou=subcontainer,ou=container,dc=domain,dc=com). But this is not very user friendly and I'd like to add a button there to open a browser (like the left panel if you run dsa.msc) to select the path. I found a specially created browser for that, but it's again made of the text strings, which could be confusing for low-skilled technicians. Some of the people supposed to use this script are just skilled enough to create and modify a user in a GUI, but don't have much deeper knowledge and have no idea what that string means, so I'd like to have the classical gui from active directory users and computers. I tried  to search classes under `system.directoryservices.activedirectory` but didn't find anything that could display the dialog

Comment: There is no AD explorer control from Microsoft that you can plug into your program. You will either have to make your own or look for a third party control.

Comment: I think this will point you towards what you are looking for - https://gist.github.com/supercheetah/b68023f3254dfc9a6497

Comment: A quick web search using 'PowerShell AD browser' also takes you to this... Stackexchange
PowerShell Active Directory Browser, --- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55056/powershell-active-directory-browser --- which leads to the authors winform  implementation --- https://adexploder.codeplex.com/ --- and his sourcce code here: ---https://adexploder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#adexploder.ps1 ---. It's a bit dated, but shodul give you direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed here: https://gist.github.com/supercheetah/b68023f3254dfc9a6497 - posted in comment by CraftyB